# VsCode Intellisense react native not working

Tags: react-native, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I am facing the problem. I am not getting intellisense of properties onPress onLongPress, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertial even in import when I type Touch then expected Suggestion will be Touchable, TouchableOpacity etc no any suggestion working in react native in vscode.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone still look for a solution,
here, install this npm package `@types/react-native` by typing in terminal:

```
npm install --save @types/react-native
```

[This is where I found the solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/huav4g/intellisense_does_not_work_for_react_native/)

Answer (score 0):

So i found an easy solution to this. All you have to do is change your language mode from JavaScript to JavaScript React.

But that only fixes the auto complete issue, to also fix the auto import you can install this vs code extension called npm Intellisense by Christian Kohler.
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense

Answer (score -4):

You will need to install an extension in VsCode to get that functionality.

[vscode-react-native](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native)

To install and use the extension, just follow the steps provided from that github repository.

Happy coding!