# Not getting IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to code a React Native application in Visual Studio Code. But I found that the hint for React Native for Styles element didn’t show when I code. I already installed:

```
 ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
 React Native Tools
 Simple React Snippets
```

Here is the example when I type flex. It is supposed to show a list of styles element related to flex but it didn’t. Is anyone know how to enable it? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my settings.json file

```
{
    "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_211",
    "java.help.firstView": "gettingStarted",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.languageServer": "Default",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "php.suggest.basic": false,
    "php.validate.enable": false,
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "markdown",
        "php"
    ],
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "php.debug.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "vs-color-picker.autoLaunch": true,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "typescript": "typescriptreact",
    },
}
```

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio Code after installing those plugins ?

Comment: yes, I also tried to restart my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by following this post:

[VsCode Intellisense react native not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827718/vscode-intellisense-react-native-not-working)

Which is installing this npm package into your project. By entering this command inside the terminal window of your VS Code:

`npm install --save @types/react-native`

Thanks for the help!